# Using mysql how to find 1st occurrence of a alphabet in a string

Tags: mysql, sql

Using mysql I need to find the position of the 1st occurrence of any alphabet in a sub string.
For example if my string is like `123456A12345` then I need to find the position of A.
My main goal is to get all the digits just before the alphabet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get all the digits, just convert the string to an integer by adding 0:

```
select '12345abc'+0
```

returns 12345.

This does not handle leading 0s.  And, it won't work for any length expression, but it may solve your problem quickly.

Comment: Hey Gordon thanks for the reply. Your solution works fine with most of the sub string values, however when there's an 'E' letter in the string the o/p I get is exponential. eg: 1931234E432 1.94E+49

Comment: Hey Gordon. I was able to get the required number after converting E with A in the substring & then adding it with 0